# Cropping a Matlab array?

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, crop

```
fname = dir('*sir');
[tmp, head] = loadsir(fname(1).name);
dayh99 = zeros(length(fname),size(tmp,1),size(tmp,2));  %41-100,1360,3600

% use temporary array to simplify 3d array creation
for i=1:length(fname)
  tmp = loadsir(fname(i).name);
  dayh99(i,:,:) = tmp;
end
```

My area of interest is the

```
   dayh99(i,:,:) = tmp;
```

tmp is basically an array 1360X3600. The problem is I don't need to store that entire array into dayh99. (It represents image data and I'm only interested in part of that image.) I'm not exactly sure yet which part of the array I need since I haven't been able to plot the data nor crop it. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know what part of the image you want, how would we?

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto you seem like a photographer, surely you must know

Comment: You can crop by assigning [] to a portion of the array.  e.g. tmp(end-10:end,:) = [];

Comment: Until I can crop the array and see the image I won't know which part of the array I need.

Comment: Perhaps plot it? `figure; imagesc(tmp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put just a portion of tmp into dayh99, just use indexing:

```
j1 = 10
j2 = 12
k1 = 10
k2 = 12

dayh99 = zeros(length(fname), j2-j1, k2-k1)
dayh99(i, :, :) = tmp([j1:j2], [k1:k2])
```

I also don't know if this is a bug, but I don't think there is a function called loadsir, unless you created it.

Comment: Yeah It's a file used to read these ".sir" files. I'll try that.

Comment: Yeah I tried this but didn't work. [Example](http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/434/4f8f6f9e100446ddadf3227.png)

Answer (score 0):

How you crop arrays in matlab is by slicing them, like so:

```
cropped_array=array(1:10,1:10)
```

You can also do cool stuff like:

```
cropped_array=array(1:10:100,1:10:100)
```

which will put only every 10th variable into the list.

Comment: Well it worked from 1:x... but not when I increased 1. How would I adjust zeros to match dayh99?                  
    `dayh99 = zeros(length(fname),610,620);
    dayh99(i,:,:) = tmp(240:850,130:750);`

Comment: Essentially, the size of both arrays has to match. So you would need to put the same region into the dayh99 call, `dayh99(i,240:850,130:750)`, or offset it somehow, say, but subtracting the first number out of it, like `dayh99(i,1:611,1:621)`.

Comment: Yeah I'm just wondering how I would adjust the zeros to match it.

Comment: Sorry I'm dumb. So I actually got the island in interest. Any reason why there's a bunch of red in the plot? It doesn't maximize it up [see here](http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/506/2bc9e702042a46369c7631b.png)

Comment: Not seeing your plot, I can only guess that the color scale is way off... Look at `caxis`